# How to avoid erasing static fields of imported and mocked services in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

In Jest, how do I avoid erasing static fields of imported and mocked services?

For example, here is an `Awesomeness` service:

```
class Awesomeness {
  static get AWESOME_VALUE() {
    return '42';
  }
  doSomethingAwesome() {
    // Implementation
  }
}
```

I'm importing this service as part of a bigger library and using `Awesomeness.AWESOME_VALUE` in my code.

Now I need to to unit-test my code, so I'm mocking the module:

```
const mockSomethingAwesome = jest.fn();
jest.mock('big-library', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('big-library'),
  Awesomeness: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
    doSomethingAwesome: mockSomethingAwesome
  }))
}));
```

Now the whole module is mocked, so when running unit test `Awesomeness.AWESOME_VALUE` is `undefined` - which, obviously, breaks some internal logic.

At this point I don't really care if I get the original value in tests or have an ability to set a mocked/fake value - I just need a way to have it defined.

Any ideas, please?